# Is it possible to use Custom Attributes to enforce a method signature

Tags: c#, reflection, attributes

I'm looking to use `reflection` in my rules engine and I'm thinking of using `CustomAttributes` to access the `methods` in my `class` (methods are the "rules" for the engine).

I am wondering if there is some way to enforce that a method follows a certain signature.

```
[RuleAttribute(typeof(long))]
public double NumericRule(string key, long source, long target)
{
  //Implementation
}
```

Is there a way to do this? Obviously only a single method will have this exact signature so no issues with multiple methods. Just wondering if there's a way of enforcing this?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm looking to restrict the use of a the attribute to a method with a certain signature. You can restrict the use of the attribute to only properties or methods etc.

Comment: Ah, got it. You want to restrict the [AttributeUsage](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/attributes/attributeusage) (especially [AttributeTargets](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.attributetargets)). There seems to be no way to restrict it to a certain signature (just `Method` in general).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there is no way to enforce the signature of a method using an Attribute.